# What should I do when encountering 'IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0' during training of a skin detection model on Colab?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, index-error

I'm a newcomer in this field.
Recently i was training a skin detection model on Colab, and this error occurred

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-68-bb8326040b37> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 train_img=preprocess_input(x_train)
      2 test_img=preprocess_input(x_test)

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py in _preprocess_numpy_input(x, data_format, mode)
    238                 x[:, 2, :, :] /= std[2]
    239     else:
--> 240         x[..., 0] -= mean[0]
    241         x[..., 1] -= mean[1]
    242         x[..., 2] -= mean[2]

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

this is the code relevant to it:

```
def load_data(input_size=(100,100)):
    images=[]
    images2=[]
    train_df,test_df=data_dictionary()
    for i in train_df['image_path']:
        img=cv2.imread(i)
        img=cv2.resize(img,input_size)
        images.append(img)
    y_train=np.asarray(train_df['target'])
    x_train=np.asarray(images)
    for i in test_df['image_path']:
        img=cv2.imread(i)
        img=cv2.resize(img,input_size)
        images2.append(img)
    y_test=np.asarray(test_df['target'])
    x_test=np.asarray(images2)
    return x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=load_data(input_size=(100,100))

train_img=preprocess_input(x_train)
test_img=preprocess_input(x_test)
```

i'm pretty new to stackoverflow so forgive me if i say something misunderstanding.

```
def data_dictionary():
    path_train="../input/dermnet/train/"
    path_test="../input/dermnet/test/"
    list_train=train_list_mod#os.listdir(path_train)
    train_dictionary={"image_path":[],"target":[]}
    test_dictionary={"image_path":[],"target":[]}
    k=0
    for i in list_train:
        path_disease_train=path_train+i
        path_disease_test=path_test+i
        image_list_train=os.listdir(path_disease_train)
        for j in image_list_train:
            img_path_train=path_disease_train+"/"+j
            train_dictionary["image_path"].append(img_path_train)
            train_dictionary['target'].append(k)
```

Comment: You need to understand what is in the loaded data, such as the `xtrain`.  How many images did you load?  That appears to depend on `train_df['image_path']`.  Is that path valid?  And image files there?  New posters often run code they borrowed from someone else, and often don't understand what's going on.  They don't know how to check what's working.  We can only guess what you know, and what's on your computer.

Comment: i took it from kaggle, but it runs normally on kaggle notebooks, when i copy to colab then this happened. I've changed all the path to my drive

Comment: Most likely it can't find or access the image files.  That's a hard thing to help with remotely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such type of error occur when your array is empty [].
Maybe problem here - emptiness of `x_train` array.

```
x = np.array([])
x[0]
```

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: i don't think the x_train array is empty since i've defined 'x_train=np.asarray(images)'  , maybe because i left images empty ?

Comment: Can you provide shape of x_train? x_train.shape. First dimension should be >= 1. Maybe because train_df['image_path'] is empty, images list dont have any images? And because of this function load_data return empty x_train.

Comment: oh, it output (0, )what should i do ?ive added my dataframe above

Comment: What variable train_df['image_path'] from load_data function contain? Do it have any path to image or it empty list too?

Comment: i think image_path is empty list too, but why i run this successfully in kaggle but encounter this error in Colab. I don't understand. This is the model i've been working on: https://www.kaggle.com/code/aditikesarwani/skin-disease-detection/notebook

Comment: Do you download train dataset from Kaggle to Google Colab? If yes, what is the path to this dataset?

Comment: /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/Data/SkinData/input/dermnet here's the path to this dataset

Comment: Try import os and insert print(os.path.abspath(path_train)) inside data_dictionary function. Does it equal to /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/Data/SkinData/input/dermnet ? By default your working directory with notebook is /content. If this is so you should change path_train to ../content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/Data/SkinData/input/dermnet/train

Comment: /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/Data/SkinData/input/dermnet/train

(Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [image_path, target]
 Index: [],) this is what it's saying after i showed the function

Comment: oh my god, i've just realized. the data in my drive was totally empty, maybe the internet problem cause the upload like this. Thanks alot, you helped me .